# F(x)=2x (x<5)、F(x)=x**2 (5<x<30) みたいにF(x)が変化するような関数をプロットしたい

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

xの条件によって、F(x)が変化する関数をグラフにプロットしたい。
[image: tho]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000)

def A(x):
    if x < 5.0:
        return 2*x 
    elif 5.0 < x < 30:
        return x**2
    elif 30 < x:
        return -3*x

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.grid()
ax.plot(x,A(x))
ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
plt.show()
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b2084c7db5ab> in <module>
     17 ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
     18 ax.grid()
---> 19 ax.plot(x,A(x))
     20 ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
     21 plt.show()

<ipython-input-3-b2084c7db5ab> in A(x)
      7 
      8 def A(x):
----> 9     if x < 5.0:
     10         return 2*x
     11     elif 5.0 < x < 30:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

関数`A(x)`の引数がNumpy配列なので、以下のようにしてみました。
`A(x)`の引数で5.0と30が定義されてないので、その場合は`np.nan`としてあります。

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000)

def A(x):
    lst = []
    for i in x:
        if i < 5.0:
            lst.append(2*i) 
        elif 5.0 < i < 30:
            lst.append(i**2)
        elif 30 < i:
            lst.append(-3*i)
        else:
            lst.append(np.nan)
    return lst

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.grid()
ax.plot(x, A(x))
ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)


a=2*x
b=x**2
c=-3*x

def K(x,a,b,c):
    if x < 5.0:
        f=a
    elif 5.0 < x < 30:
        f=b
    elif 30 < x:
        f=c
    return f

vec_K = np.vectorize(K)
y = vec_K(x,a,b,c)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```